# Parse error while running my php code

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help with the error I am receiving?

**Error**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in activation.php
```

**Code**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if ($_GET['id'] != "") {    

  include_once "../scripts/connection.php";

  $id = $_GET['id']; 
  $hashpass = $_GET['sequence']; 

  $id  = mysql_real_escape_string($id );
  $id = eregi_replace("`", "", $id);

  $hashpass = mysql_real_escape_string($hashpass);
  $hashpass = eregi_replace("`", "", $hashpass);

  // activates member by adding a 1 to activated in the database //

  $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE memberAdmin SET activated='1' WHERE id='$id' AND password='$hashpass'");   
  $sql_doublecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memberAdmin WHERE id='$id' AND password='$hashpass' AND activated='1'"); 
  $doublecheck = mysql_num_rows($sql_doublecheck); 

  // shows this info on the msgToUser.php page //

  if($doublecheck = 0){ 
    $msgToUser = "<p><strong>Blackberry Creek Mini Farm Newsletter Site</strong></p>
<p><strong>Sorry, your account could not be activated!</strong></p><br />
<p>Please click the Contact Us link below to email the site administrator and request manual activation.</p>"; 
    include 'msgToUser.php'; 
    exit();
  } elseif ($doublecheck > 0) { 

    $msgToUser = "<h1>Welcome to the Blackberry Creek Mini Farm Newsletter Site</h1>
                  <h2>Your membership has been activated!</h2>      
                  <p>Please<strong> 
                     <a href="news.galink.net/users/login.php">Log In</a>
                  </strong></p>
                  <p>Thank you for joining the Blackberry Creek Mini Farm Newsletter Site</p>";     

    include 'msgToUser.php'; 
    exit();
   } 
 } 

print "Sorry, essential data from the activation URL is missing! Close your browser, go back to your email inbox, and please use the full URL supplied in the activation link we sent you.<br />
<br />blackberrycreekminifarm@gmail.com<br />";
?>
```

Comment: perhaps you might want to provide some soure code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your double quotes in the following line:

```
<p>Please<strong> <a href="news.galink.net/users/login.php">Log In</a></strong></p>
```

using `\`.

```
<p>Please<strong> <a href=\"news.galink.net/users/login.php\">Log In</a></strong></p>
```

Comment: ty will make the change

Answer (score 1):

First off, `if($doublecheck = 0)` should probably be a `==` instead.

Second, you have `"`'s within a string that was created with `"`'s. You should change it to this. Using `\` to escape the `"`'s within the `$msgToUser`. You could also just change the first and last quotes to apostrophies

```
$msgToUser = "<h1>Welcome to the Blackberry Creek Mini Farm Newsletter Site</h1>

<h2>Your membership has been activated!</h2>        

<p>Please<strong> <a href=\"news.galink.net/users/login.php\">Log In</a></strong></p>

<p>Thank you for joining the Blackberry Creek Mini Farm Newsletter Site</p>";
```

Comment: ty will make changes and try again

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 38:

```
<p>Please<strong> <a href="news.galink.net/users/login.php">Log In</a></strong></p>
```

Since you have the string in double-quotes, you'll want to escape the quotes on that line, or use single quotes

```
<p>Please<strong> <a href=\"news.galink.net/users/login.php\">Log In</a></strong></p>
```

OR

```
<p>Please<strong> <a href='news.galink.net/users/login.php'>Log In</a></strong></p>
```

Comment: ty will change and try again